# Where to download & install Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview Version 17.8.0 Preview 5.0

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-preview

The current version of visual studio on Microsoft official website is below:

**Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview version 17.10.0 Preview 2.0**

But I have been asked to download and install below version:

**Visual Studio Community 2022 Preview version 17.8.0 Preview 5.0**

But I'm unable to find it anywhere, can somebody help me put a link to that particular version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't recall there being a Preview 5.0 _ever_ for any of the major version releases.  Regardless, why do you even need that specific version?